# Windows XP + Gmail + Firefox = Bad?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, gmail

The latest version of Gmail just stopped working on Firefox for me. I am using version 3.5.5.

I'm sure this has happened to others. I don't want to reinstall the program since I have a ton of plugins.

My operating system is Windows XP.

I can load the basic HTML version but not the standard view version....

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: Start disabling extensions.

Comment: To add on what heavyd said, disable an addon at a time and see if one is bugging out if Qberticus's answer doesnt work.

Comment: As heavyd said, one-by-one, try seeing if an extension killed it. Try restarting Firefox in safe mode (there's a shortcut in the start menu group). This will load it without any extensions. See if gmail works then. If so, then one of your extensions is conflicting with some script or something in gmail, and you need to one-by-one enable them to see which one kills it. Then decided if you prefer to have gmail, or that extension and stop using one or the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clear your firefox disk cache and then shift+reload gmail.

Comment: This happens to me sometimes. The above fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that GMail's standard view requires both Flash and Javascript. If you have anything blocking Flash or Javascript, chances are the standard view won't work. I know flash is required as disabling Flash in Chrome makes GMail not load at all, not even the loading bar. So I figure, it must be a requirement (albeit a pretty stupid one); and Javascript is required as everything in GMail needs Javascript.

Comment: Flash is needed only if you have the Gmail voice and video chat plugin